# Problema com ordenação de vetor em C

Tags: c, array

Estou tentando fazer esse problema, mas sempre o resultado dá errado.

> "Faça um programa que crie um vetor de 10 posições preenchido pelo usuário. Varra o vetor e sempre que o valor da posição i do vetor for menor do que o valor da posição i+1 você deve trocá-los de lugar."

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int i,vet[10],aux;
    aux = 0;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("Digite um valor:\n");
        scanf("%d",&vet[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {

        if(vet[i]<vet[i+1])
        {   

            aux = vet[i];
            vet[i] = vet[i+1];
            vet[i+1] = aux;


        }   
    }


    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",vet[i]);

    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você está verificando uma única vez seu vetor. Se houver alguma troca você tem que verificar todo o vetor novamente, até que não ocorra nenhuma troca. Portanto faltou um loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está tentando fazer a ordenação utilizando o método bolha correto? , assim ficaria o programa(em ordem crescente):

mas antes o resumo sobre ordenação:
Exemplo: a=10 b=5 , eu não posso trocar os valores deles para ordenar simplesmente direto dizendo que a=b ou b=a pois eu perco os valores , por isso eu preciso de uma auxiliar para armazenar o valor a ser trocado.Se eu fosse colocar em ordem crescente:

1-Vou trocar o valor de b que vai passar para a

auxiliar=b
b=a
a=auxiliar

resultado:
a=5 b=10

*se atente para nomes de variáveis para não ter problemas lá na frente ^^

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int valor[10];
    int auxiliar;

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("Digite um valor:\n");
        scanf("%d",&valor[i]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1; j<10; j++)
        {
            if(valor[i]>valor[j])
            { 
                auxiliar=valor[i];
                valor[i]=valor[j];
                valor[j]=auxiliar;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",valor[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Desculpe editar tanto , tentei complementar ao máximo !

Comment: Uma vez que o código da pergunta está indentado o seu também devia estar, até porque facilita a leitura.

Comment: sim , infelizmente não consigo fazer indentação neste fórum , não sei se é algum bug mas ficar digitando space 5 mil vezes não dá!

Comment: Quando copia o código do editor e ele já vem indentando do editor então não é preciso fazer nada. Basta aplicar formatação de código selecionando o código e clicando no botão `{}` do editor da resposta ou pressionando `Ctrl + k`.

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma de fazer é utilizando o algoritmo de Swap XOR onde você pode efetuar a troca de valores sem o uso de uma variável auxiliar.

```
int main() 
{

    int i, vet[10], aux;
    aux = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("Digite um valor:\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &vet[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (vet[i] < vet[i + 1])
        {
            // Operação SWAP XOR
            vet[i] ^= vet[i + 1];
            vet[i + 1] ^= vet[i];
            vet[i] ^= vet[i + 1];
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", vet[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Se quiseres saber um pouco mais, tem uma referência [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826159/swapping-two-variable-value-without-using-third-variable)

Comment: Como você compara o elemento i com o i+1 então seu loop deve ser de 0 até 8, e não até 9. for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)